# serialize/json_encode to one field or keep raw data in many fields of db?

Tags: php, mysql, json, performance, serialization

Since five days i am thinking about how to store data in my new project. I've read a lot of articles about advantages and disadvantages of serializing or json_encoding, also about searching database with thousands of records. Here's the problem.

Consider i am making a game - i have thousands of locations and every location may have a some objects in it. The ammount of objects is limited but i guess may be 10-20 objects on each location. Each object has some properties (like perks), which sometimes needs to be checked, updated and so on, so i have to store it in db.

I see two options to do it:

- simple database way, working with first database normalization form - store each object as a row in database and each property - in columns. I can easily retrieve data, connect it to specific location with just one id. The problem is that there may be (and there will be) a thousands of rows in db - all objects * ammount of location and searching it might be very expensive in time. If you multiply it by number of players searching database simultaneously it can kill DB.
- second way is to serialize or json encode (or even implode somhow) all the objects in current loaction with all its properties. I guess each object may have 100 properties * 20 objects serialized might be not so small array of values. So 2000 (assoc key + int value) elements serialized and saved in one field for each location. There is a lot less database searching - just set id as primary key and search for it but later i have to deserialize all the data. It also might be expensive.

I know i dont put any code in here (there isnt any yet) so it is quite virtual question but i wonder if u ever checked what is better solution - to store large ammount of data in one filed but have it serialized or to have it scattered into db for multiple rows.

Hope you can share your experience:)

Kalreg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relational database searching is insanely fast. It's also incredibly flexible if you set it up right. So the encode process will be the most time costly factor. The benefit of JSON is server-client data transfer. Personally I'd use the tried-and-true Option 1 but look to cache as much data client-side as possible, e.g. HTML storage.

I also note you're using PHP. An AJAX approach with minimal page reloads is what you want, although I may be over-reading your tag.

Comment: thats true i mentioned about php because serverside part would be done in php. rest of course with ajax. thank u for your answer - hope the time will show that Option 1 was a good choice :)

Comment: Great. I don't imagine you'll regret the choice :)

Answer (score 1):

You will want the first method.

Comment: Well for starters, what happens down the road when you want to change how an object works, but now you have to parse massive object fields manually to update every instance of it, instead of a simple UPDATE query?

Comment: If you really wanted, you could try and do a hybrid system; have database backing it all split out, and have a caching layer that will store all the objects as one block. That way you can still update things nicely and just rebuild your cache from the DB.